# Why is slither.io CPU intensive?

Tags: resources, cpu-usage

From a programmer's point of view, how can a snakes and dots game consume much more resources than many other more advanced games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the calculations are done by the CPU, whereas other computation-intensive games tend to make use of the GPU. You can observe this by looking at your CPU monitor/task manager, and your graphics driver configuration interface (if you have a fancy card).

When I load the slither game my GPU temp doesn't increase at all, whereas the CPU temp climbs steadily, and the game immediately swallows half of my cores. CPU use further increases in "busy" periods when there are many other players interacting in a small area.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy programming.

Considering you could run the original Quake, a fully 3D game with texture mapping on a Pentium 66 Mhz with 16 Mb RAM without a 3D accelerator card, there is no reason for a silly 2D browser snake game to stall on a modern multi-Ghz CPU other than programmer incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Slither.io is calculating block chain while we play the game. in such cases the game would run smoother on an old graphics card where their secondary intention is not possible. The greater the GPU the more time of the game is split for their nefarious purposes.